# NODE / UPDATE / API / SEQUELIZE: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null

Tags: node.js, api, null, sequelize.js, put

**EDIT:**
The problem was precisely in the authentication (in fact it was working properly, however, the token was referring to the old user's id in the database):

```
   const { email, oldPassword } = req.body;

   const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId);

   if (email !== user.email) {
     const userExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

     if (userExists) {
       return res.status(400).send({ error: 'User already exists.' });
     }
   }
```

***Probably, after I manually made changes to the database, the token did not recognize this. (I also put in a 7-day expiration)***

**EDIT /\**

**error:**

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "email", "password_hash", "provider", "created_at" AS "createdAt", "updated_at" AS "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = 7;
(node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
    at update (C:\Project\src\app\controllers\UserController.js:56:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate 
the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

P.S:
`WHERE "User"."id" = 7;`

*(the ID in the user's database would be = 1, in this case)*

*This line represents*:

`at update (C:\Project\src\app\controllers\UserController.js:56:24)`

*This part of the code on UserController:*

```
if (email !== user.email) {   // <<<---- Here
      const userExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

      if (userExists) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'User already exists.' });
      }
    }
```

**Understanding the problem:**

I am making an API in Node.js, where I am trying to do a **user update**

*I am using sequelize (PostgreSQL) in the database using Docker (myself as a begginer, I thought about the possibility that it was a problem with Docker/Database/Sequelize, because I created 10 fake users and inserted it in the database, after that, I removed all (manually, on Postbird) and of course the first new user_ID would become, 11, for example). Then, I created a new database and the user was created normally with id1.*

I considered that the user could only update his information if he was authenticated in:
`routes.use(authMiddleware);` (in ./src/routes.js)

- *I didn't put the authentication I did here, I believe it's working 100%.*

Here is the project's architecture:

**./src/routes.js**

```
import { Router } from 'express';

import UserController from './app/controllers/UserController';

import authMiddleware from './app/middlwares/auth';

const routes = new Router();

routes.use(authMiddleware);

routes.put('/users', UserController.update);

export default routes;
```

**.src/app/controllers/UserController.js**

```
import User from '../models/User';

class UserController {
  async update(req, res) {
    const { email, oldPassword } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId);

    if (email !== user.email) {
      const userExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

      if (userExists) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'User already exists.' });
      }
    }

    if (oldPassword && !(await user.checkPassword(oldPassword))) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Password does not match' });
    }

    const { id, name, provider } = await user.update(req.body);

    return res.json({
      id,
      name,
      email,
      provider,
    });
  }
}

export default new UserController();
```

**./src/app/models/User.js**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        password_hash: Sequelize.STRING,
        provider: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
      if (user.password) {
        user.password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
      }
    });

    return this;
  }

  checkPassword(password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash);
  }
}

export default User;
```

**./src/database/migrations/number-create-users.js**

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNulll: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNulll: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password_hash: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
      provider: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  },
};
```

**HTTP / PUT JSON Data:**

```
{
    "name": "user000",
    "email": "email000@domain.com.br",
    "oldPassword": "password000",
    "password": "123456",
    "confirmPassword": "123456"
}
```

*Consdering that the user is already authenticated.*

Comment: I'm sur I understand exactly what you did. But if in the database you only have one user with ID 1, and if you try to find a user with id 7, Sequelize will not find the user and it will return a null object. So the resultant seems to be ok. You just need to check if the object is null before checking the email.

Comment: Thank you, what you said was really happening, it was due to authentication, I explained in the edit above

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the user is not found by the below query. therefore `user` might be  `undefined`. Are you sure that this line is correct?

```
    const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId);
```

and `userId` shouldn't be either in the body of the request or in the `params`? i.e.:

```
    const user = await User.findByPk(req.params.userId);
```

If the user id is in the params, I think you also need to update your `route` to:

```
routes.put('/users/:userId', UserController.update);
```

Furthermore I think its a good practice to wrap async stuff into a try catch block. something like this:

```
try {

 const user = await User.findByPk(req.params.userId);

} catch (err) {

console.log(err)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention, actually, through the authentication middleware (in the request / req) I was able to pass the 'user_id' and then he recognized it. The problem was with the authentication referring to another id (since I had not updated). I also thank you to remember me about  try and catch for async.


If you don't know how to pass an object's body through middleware visit this link for more information:
[link](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-node-js-middleware-works-d8e02a936113)